# How can I disable the button at the end of this component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, use-ref, disabled-control

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'    
import Input from '../../UI/Input'

import classes from './MealItemForm.module.css'

export default function MealItemForm(props) {
  const [amountIsValid, setAmountIsValid] = useState(true)

  const amountInputRef = useRef()

  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const enteredAmount = amountInputRef.current.value
    const enteredAmountNumber = +enteredAmount

    if (enteredAmount.trim().length === 0 || enteredAmountNumber < 1 || enteredAmountNumber > 20) {
      setAmountIsValid(false)
      return
    }

    props.onAddToCart(enteredAmountNumber)
  }
```

Tried to add a function after submitHandler to disabled the button when the enteredAmountNumber > 20, but couldn't make it working!

```
  return (
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <Input
        ref={amountInputRef}
        label='Amount'
        input={{
          id: 'amount_' + props.id,
          type: 'number',
          min: '1',
          max: '20',
          step: '1',
          defaultValue: '1'
        }}
      />
      {/* Two curly braces: one for embedding javascript expression and the other one is there because the value is object */}
```

I want to disable this button when the enteredAmount > 20, please help me!

```
      <button>+ Add</button>

      {!amountIsValid && <p>Please enter a valid amount(1~20)</p>}
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Add the attribute `disabled={enteredAmount>20} to the button`?

Comment: add a `useState` that tracks the entered amount and add an attribute to the button `disabled={enteredAmount > 20}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `disabled` attribute of `button`

```
<button disabled={enteredAmountNumber > 20}>Enter Amount</button>
```

**Code based on your comment**

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'    
import Input from '../../UI/Input'

import classes from './MealItemForm.module.css'

export default function MealItemForm(props) {
  const [amountIsValid, setAmountIsValid] = useState(true)

  const amountInputRef = useRef()

  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const enteredAmount = amountInputRef.current.value
    const enteredAmountNumber = +enteredAmount

    if (enteredAmount.trim().length === 0 || enteredAmountNumber < 1 || enteredAmountNumber > 20) {
      setAmountIsValid(false)
      return
    }

    props.onAddToCart(enteredAmountNumber)
  }

return (
    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <Input
        ref={amountInputRef}
        label='Amount'
        input={{
          id: 'amount_' + props.id,
          type: 'number',
          min: '1',
          max: '20',
          step: '1',
          defaultValue: '1'
        }}
      />
      {/* Two curly braces: one for embedding javascript expression and the other one is there because the value is object */}

   <button disabled={!amountIsValid}>+ Add</button>

      {!amountIsValid && <p>Please enter a valid amount(1~20)</p>}
    </form>
  )
}
```

**UPDATE based on your comment**

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]

```
import "./styles.css";
import react, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button
        disabled={clickCount >= 20}
        onClick={() => {
          setClickCount((clickCount) => clickCount + 1);
        }}
      >
        {clickCount === 0 ? `Click Me` : `You clicked ${clickCount} times`}{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it gives --> enteredAmount is not defined

Comment: You need to define that variable. or in your case it will be `enteredAmountNumber`. I have changed that in my code.

Comment: Yeah I have tried enteredAmountNumber, but that does not work, because it is defined in submitHandler method, maybe that's why the button doesn't get enteredAmountNumber

Comment: if I extract the amountInputRef.current.value into a new variable and then make it a number and gives it a name value then also gives this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Comment: I have updated code. please  check it.

Comment: still don't work, no error this time but the button is not disabled after 20 press

Comment: your condition is more than 20. so enter 21 or change the condition

Comment: still it is not working?

Comment: No not working, I wanted the button to work like this: it will be disabled when it will be pressed 20 times i.e. the enteredAmountNumber > 20, that doesn't work passing the amountIsValid state.

Comment: finally, I understand your requirement. please check the updated part

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, Can I be connected with your LinkedIn profile?

Comment: yes sure. https://www.linkedin.com/in/khabiruddin/